# Ajax Get returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I'm a total Rails beginner and I'm pretty lost on how to fix this error. I am trying to call the `get_info_from_iclass` method which is in my `rentals_controller` at my javascript file.

```js
$('document').ready(function () {

var iclass_field = document.getElementById("ic").getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
console.log(iclass_field == null);
let timeout;
iclass_field.addEventListener("input", () => {
clearTimeout(timeout);
 timeout = setTimeout(() => populateFields(iclass_field), 500);
  });

    function populateFields(iclass) {
      var temp = iclass.value;
      var studIC = parseInt(temp);
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "rentals/get_info_from_iclass",
        data: {studIC: studIC},
        dataType: 'text',
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
          document.getElementById("fn").getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value = data.first_name;
          document.getElementById("ln").getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value = data.last_name;
          document.getElementById("em").getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value = data.email_address;
        },
            error: function(data) {
                alert("Fail");
            }
      });
  }
});
```

Eventually, I'm trying to populate the other fields in the form with the data returned by a db query that I'm making using the `iclass` in the Controller. Below is the method in my controller that I'm trying to call.

```ruby
def get_info_from_iclass
   return User.where(iclass: params[:iclass]).last
  end
```

However, no matter what I try the request returns undefined. From searching other stackoverflow topics I think it may have something to do with the fact that AJAX is asynchronous and I have to do something with callback methods(???). Again I am very new at this and would love an in depth explanation of whats going on if that is possible with the amount of information I have given.

### EDIT

I tried using a callback function but alas, I ran into the same issue with my data being undefined.

```js
  success: update_form,
  error: function(data) {
      alert("Fail");
    }
  });
function update_form(data){
document.getElementById("fn").getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value = data.first;
..etc....
```

Could it perhaps be the way I'm querying the database? or the way I'm handling the data type?

Comment: try to change **$.get("rentals/get_info_from_iclass", studIC, function (data) {** to **$.get("rentals/get_info_from_iclass", {studIC : studIC}, function (data) {**

Comment: this is wrong: **ignoreReturn(iclass_field));** In this way you execute the function and the resulting value is undefined. Hence, when on keypress that handler is called again no action is done. Why does it work? Because on the first call you have this line: **iclass_field.onkeypress = function(e){**

Comment: @gaetanoM changing it to  {studIC : studIC} yields same error.. and when I comment out the line ignoreReturn(iclass_field) nothing is called. What should I be passing in to the addEventListener then instead?

Answer (score 0):

You have more than one error:

- iclass_field.addEventListener("keypress", ignoreReturn(iclass_field));

  In this way you call immediately the function and, because that function retuns undefined that handler will be never called. But you added again the handler inside the function.
- if (key = 13) {

  In this way you assign the value 13  instead of testing the value itself
- Because you are not interested in **\n** you can simplify your code using the [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) event.
- The correct way to pass parameters to the [jQuery get](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) function is **{studIC: studIC}**

Moreover, if you have a form and don't want to submit the form itself you may prevent it using the submit [event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/submit).

```js
$('document').ready(function () {

    var iclass_field = document.getElementById("ic").getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
    iclass_field.addEventListener("input", function (e) {
        populateFields(iclass_field); // you may use the this keyword.....
    });


    function populateFields(iclass) {
        var temp = iclass.value;
        var studIC = parseInt(temp);
        $.get("rentals/get_info_from_iclass", {studIC: studIC}, function (data) {
            alert('Success');
        });
    }
});
```